# Combinatorics with Number Sets and Correlation Calculation in Python

Tags: python, set, iteration, correlation, combinatorics

I have a bit of a combinatorics problem that I’m having difficulty even conceptualizing how I would go about it using itertools.  My dataset looks like this:

```
GoldMeasure Measure1 Measure2 Measure3 Measure4 Measure5 3+4-5

  30.501       -1      -1       -1        -1       -1     -1
  30.658       -1      -1        0        -1       -1      0
  31.281       -1               -1        -1        1     -3
  31.506        7      -1       -1         1       -1      1
  31.554       -1      -1       -1        -1       -1     -1
  31.613       -1      -1       -1         1               0
  31.838       -1      -1       -1        -1              -2
  31.954       -1      -1       -1         1       -1      1
  33.073        1       1                  1       -1      2
  33.592       -2      -2        2         0       -2      4

Coefficient: -0.054    0.119   0.690     0.474   -0.441  0.723
```

I’m trying to find the best combination of Measures 1-5 that has the highest Pearson’s correlation coefficient with the Gold Measure.  In the dataset above, the best single measure is Measure Three with a coefficient of 0.69.  However, if you add Measure Three to Measure Four and then subtract Measure Five you get a new combination measure that has a coefficient of 0.72.  Essentially, I want to determine the correlation coefficient for all possible combinations of these five measures.  These combinations can be 2/5 of the measures, 3/5 of the measures (like in the example above), 4/5 of the measures or all five measures.

Order is somewhat important.  It is true that the additive combination of Measures 3, 4, and 5 is the same as the additive combination of 5, 3, and 4; however, I am also trying to include the arithmetic operator as another option (addition or subtraction).  Thus, 3+4+5 is the same as 5+3+4 but 3+4-5 is not the same as 5+3-4.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.  The actual dataset has 46 measures and, as in the example dataset above, there are some measures that do not have values for specific samples.  The values of the measures are both negative and positive but are not bounded.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You want to consider any combination, Measure1 plus/minus Measure2 plus/minus Measure3 plus/minus Measure4 plus/minus Measure5 (except, of course, that if all the signs are minus the correlation will be the same as when all are positive)?

Comment: "The values of the measures are both negative and positive but are not bounded." What does this mean?

Comment: The values above are all within the range of -3 to +7 but they can be anything from -10000 to +10000 (although I do believe the max is usually around 20 or so).

Comment: I should have said that the coefficient of each measure is one of -1, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import statistics
import itertools
import scipy.stats
import heapq

#Please add a filename here and use a .csv format.
F=open('filename','r').readlines();

F[0].strip().split(',');
HEADER=[r.strip() for r in F[0].strip().split(',')[2:]];

DDF={};
DDP={};
DDN={};
DDG={};
#Please replace missing values using Excel into "NAA". I have replaced the "NAA"/missing values with average of the column. You may also consider ignoring missing rows before doing correlation between 2 columns.
for f in F[1:]:
    DATA=f.strip().split(',');
    ATAD=[[i.strip(),j.strip()] for i,j in zip(HEADER,DATA[2:])];
    for atad in ATAD:
        if atad[0].strip() in DDF.keys():
            DDF[atad[0].strip()].append(atad[1].strip());
        else:
            DDF[atad[0].strip()]=[atad[1].strip()];

    if F[0].strip().split(',')[1].strip() in DDG.keys():
        DDG[F[0].strip().split(',')[1].strip()].append(float(DATA[1].strip()));
    else:
        DDG[F[0].strip().split(',')[1].strip()]=[float(DATA[1].strip())];

for ke in DDF.keys():
    AVGP=statistics.mean([float(u) for u in DDF[ke.strip()] if u.strip()!='NAA']);
    NEWP=[float(nr.strip()) if nr.strip()!='NAA' else AVGP for nr in DDF[ke.strip()]];
    if ke in DDP.keys():
        DDP[ke.strip()]=NEWP;
    else:
        DDP[ke.strip()]=NEWP;
    AVGN=statistics.mean([-1*float(e) for e in DDF[ke.strip()] if e.strip()!='NAA']);
    NEWN=[-1*float(ne.strip()) if ne.strip()!='NAA' else AVGN for ne in DDF[ke.strip()]];
    if 'minus_'+ke.strip() in DDN.keys():
        DDN['minus_'+ke.strip()]=NEWN;
    else:
        DDN['minus_'+ke.strip()]=NEWN;
U=0;
L1=DDP.keys()+DDN.keys();
N=range(1,len(L1));
U=[0,0,-1];

for n in N:
    DDU=[];
    for subset in itertools.combinations(L1,n):
        S=[];
        SSET=[sset.strip().replace('minus_','') if sset.strip().startswith('minus_') else sset.strip() for sset in list(subset)];
        if len(set(SSET))>=len(subset):
            TMP=[DDN[p.strip()] if p.strip().startswith('minus_') else DDP[p.strip()] for p in subset];
            for y in range(0,len(TMP[0])):
                for x in TMP:
                    S.append(x[y]);
            SUM=[sum(S[w:w + n]) for w in range(0, len(S),n)];
            K=['+'.join(list(subset)).strip()]+[' vs Cq TREC']+list(scipy.stats.pearsonr(SUM,DDG['Cq TREC']));
            if str(K[-2])!='nan':
                DDU.append([K[-2],K]);
    DDU.sort(key=lambda x: x[0],reverse=True);
    for ea in DDU[0:3]:
        print repr(n).strip()+','+ea[1][0].strip().replace('+minus_','-').replace('minus_','-')+' '+ea[1][1].strip()+','+repr(ea[1][-2]).strip();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's feasible to do this with five measures.

```
from itertools import product
from numpy import negative, array_equal

choices = [1, 0, -1]
measures = 5
limit = len(choices)**measures//2+1
count = 0
measure_combinations = []
for p in product(*([choices]*5)):
    measure_combinations.append(list(p))
    count += 1
    if count == limit:
        break

print (len(measure_combinations))
```

For instance, the inner product of one of the measure_combinations, say [1,1,0,-1,-1] with each row of the measure columns would provide a series of values upon which GoldMeasure could be regressed to obtain a correlation coefficent, and this could be done for the 122 unique possibilities.

However, for 41 measures there would be 18,236,498,188,585,393,202 unique possibilities, based on part of the product of 41 repetitions of {-1,0,1}.

Comment: Yeouzer! Definitely need to reduce the number of measures then.  Thanks for that input. I could probably do this with as few as 10 which would be around 30,000 unique possibilities.

Comment: Even 15 looks possible, with patience. I hated to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: I really like the "coefficient of each measure" idea to simplify the problem!

Comment: How I wish it were my original idea. :) Does this mean you might accept my answer?